# R package: sourcing scripts from folder on package load

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

My idea is simple, I have a wrapper package that is ready to load and execute R and Python scripts (through `reticulate`).

Despite the requirement for a common file/code structure, the idea is that if a user wants to define a new method for the workflow (say, updated taxonomy), it would be enough to add a new script in the scripts folder (i.e., place files in `rules/`, `py/...`, and rebuild).

What is the proper way to make this work?

I've tried loading the files through `.onLoad`, i.e.,

```
.onLoad <- function(lib, pkg){
  require(reticulate) #I know require is bad practice; this is for example purposes
  files <- dir('rules')
  lapply(files, function(w){
     source(sprintf('rules/%s', w))
     source_python(sprintf("py/%s/rule.py", w))
  })
}
```

But this seems to be looking at local directories, rather than inside the package.

I have found that R is able to load `.rda` or `.RData` files from `data/` directory, or `.txt, .csv`, but that's about it. What about extensions, like sourcing files as in my example?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If ``.rda`` files are actually a limitation due to some known reasons, one possible solution could be another wrapper, to source and pack to ``.rda`` all scripts before deploying. But, weirdly, this seems even messier that the original solution. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: You are free to add any kind of data in `inst/extdata`. You can access to the path with `system.file("extdata", "file.ext", package="pkg")`. Is that a viable option for you?

Comment: @JRR Yes, it was exactly what I was looking for. You can post your comment as an answer, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder `inst/exdata` allows for adding any kind of data within an R package. This might be the right place to store `.R` or `.py` files not directly related to the core code of your package. You can access these files with `system.file("extdata", "file.ext", package="pkg")`. See also [extdata in R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html#data-extdata).